# How to get JSON out of Angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

How do i get the get JSON data out of a $resource?

Currently all return values out of `User.query` and `User.$save()` are factory objects.  I would like to be able to keep `$scope.users` as raw JSON so I can modify it and post the data to another URL.

```
 myApp.factory("User", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/users/:Id", { Id: "@Id"}, {
      "update": {method:"PUT"},
      "query": { method:"GET", isArray: true }
    });
});

var users = User.query(function() {
    $scope.users = users;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the response like this:

```
myApp.factory("User", function($resource, $http) {
    return $resource("/api/users/:Id", { Id: "@Id"}, {
        "update": {method:"PUT"},
        "query": {
            method:"GET",
            isArray: true,
                transformResponse: [function (data, headersGetter) {
                return [{ result: JSON.parse(data) }];
            }].concat($http.defaults.transformResponse)
        }
    });
});
```